# Mistake reading json

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I am trying to parse json code from url but I don´t able to see my mistake because I don´t get any result. This is my code:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
             // Creating service handler class instance
           ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall("http://api.apixu.com/v1/forecast.json?key=93a1531ba64540f7a41180856163011&q=bilbao&days=1", ServiceHandler.GET);


            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    JSONObject fore = jsonObj.getJSONObject("forecast");

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                   eventos = fore.getJSONArray("forecastday");

                   porhoraca = fore.getJSONArray("hour");


                    for (int i = 0; i < porhoraca.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = porhoraca.getJSONObject(i);

                        String hora = c.getString(TAG_TIME);
                        String tempec = c.getString(TAG_TEMP_C);
                        String sensacion = c.getString(TAG_FEELSLIKE_C);

                        JSONObject condi = c.getJSONObject(TAG_CONDITION);
                            String texto = condi.getString(TAG_TEXT);
                            String icono = condi.getString(TAG_ICON);



                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put("nombre", hora);
                        contact.put("hora", tempec);
                        contact.put("nombre_lugar", sensacion);
                        contact.put("coordenadas", texto);
                        contact.put("info", icono);



                        // adding contact to contact list
                        eventosList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;


        }
```

I only want to get this objects from the url that has the json. Some I am doing wrong. Perhaps I don´t read properly the json objects and Json arrays. Somebody can say me where is my mistake? thanks

The Json code is here:

http://api.apixu.com/v1/forecast.json?key=93a1531ba64540f7a41180856163011&q=bilbao&days=1

Comment: consider using `gson` library....it will make your life much easier!

Comment: @Androi: what data getting in ` Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);` line?

Comment: What you want to get in this from - location, forecast or current?

Comment: Debug it. Add logs. Try to log trace the json objects one after another. It helps to understand your Mistake

Comment: You can use online Json parsers like [this](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/), that will help you understand the Json object. Just copy paste the GET result and hit the viewer tab. Also, as previously suggested, I would recommend that you use one of the excellent libraries out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i implemented your code, debug it and got final result in eventosList that is here:

```
[{nombre_lugar=2.0, coordenadas=Clear, hora=2.7, nombre=2017-01-05 00:00, info=//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/night/113.png}, {nombre_lugar=1.8, coordenadas=Clear, hora=2.5, nombre=2017-01-05 01:00, info=//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/night/113.png}, {nombre_lugar=1.6, coordenadas=Clear, hora=2.4, nombre=2017-01-05 02:00, info=//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/night/113.png}, {nombre_lugar=1.4, coordenadas=Clear, hora=2.2, nombre=2017-01-05 03:00, info=//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/night/113.png}, {nombre_lugar=1.0, coordenadas=Clear, hora=2.0, nombre=2017-01-05 04:00, info=//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/night/113.png}, {nombre_lugar=0.7, coordenadas=Clear, hora=1.7, nombre=2017-01-05 05:00, info=//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/night/113.png}, {nombre_lugar=0.3, coordenadas=Clear, hora=1.5, nombre=2017-01-05 06:00, info=//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/night/113.png}, {nombre_lugar=1.0, coordenadas=Clear, hora=2.4, nombre=2017-01-05 07:00, info=//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/night/113.png}, {nombre_lugar=1.8, coordenadas=Clear, hora=3.4, nombre=2017-01-05 08:00, info=//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/night/113.png}, {nombre_lugar=2.5, coordenadas=Sunny, hora=4.3, nombre=2017-01-05 09:00, info=//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/day/113.png}, {nombre_lugar=3.9, coordenadas=Sunny, hora=5.7, nombre=2017-01-05 10:00, info=//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/day/113.png}, {nombre_lugar=5.4, coordenadas=Sunny, hora=7.1, nombre=2017-01-05 11:00, info=//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/day/113.png}, {nombre_lugar=6.8, coordenadas=Sunny, hora=8.5, nombre=2017-01-05 12:00, info=//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/day/113.png}, {nombre_lugar=7.6, coordenadas=Sunny, hora=9.1, nombre=2017-01-05 13:00, info=//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/day/113.png}, {nombre_lugar=8.3, coordenadas=Sunny, hora=9.7, nombre=2017-01-05 14:00, info=//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/day/113.png}, {nombre_lugar=9.1, coordenadas=Sunny, hora=10.3, nombre=2017-01-05 15:00, info=//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/day/113.png}, {nombre_lugar=8.5, coordenadas=Sunny, hora=9.3, nombre=2017-01-05 16:00, info=//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/day/113.png}, {nombre_lugar=7.9, coordenadas=Sunny, hora=8.3, nombre=2017-01-05 17:00, info=//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/day/113.png}, {nombre_lugar=7.3, coordenadas=Clear, hora=7.3, nombre=2017-01-05 18:00, info=//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/night/113.png}, {nombre_lugar=6.3, coordenadas=Clear, hora=6.3, nombre=2017-01-05 19:00, info=//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/night/113.png}, {nombre_lugar=5.3, coordenadas=Clear, hora=5.3, nombre=2017-01-05 20:00, info=//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/night/113.png}, {nombre_lugar=4.3, coordenadas=Clear, hora=4.3, nombre=2017-01-05 21:00, info=//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/night/113.png}, {nombre_lugar=1.5, coordenadas=Clear, hora=2.5, nombre=2017-01-05 22:00, info=//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/night/113.png}, {nombre_lugar=-1.3, coordenadas=Clear, hora=0.6, nombre=2017-01-05 23:00, info=//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/night/113.png}]
```

soultion is this try this and you will get full result :

```
 try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);

                        JSONObject fore = jsonObj.getJSONObject("forecast");

                        // Getting JSON Array node
                        JSONArray eventos = fore.getJSONArray("forecastday");


                        JSONArray porhoraca = eventos.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("hour");

                        for (int i = 0; i < porhoraca.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject c = porhoraca.getJSONObject(i);

                            String hora = c.getString("time");
                            String tempec = c.getString("temp_c");
                            String sensacion = c.getString("feelslike_c");
                            JSONObject condi = c.getJSONObject("condition");
                            String texto = condi.getString("text");
                            String icono = condi.getString("icon");


                            // tmp hashmap for single contact
                            HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            contact.put("nombre", hora);
                            contact.put("hora", tempec);
                            contact.put("nombre_lugar", sensacion);
                            contact.put("coordenadas", texto);
                            contact.put("info", icono);


                            // adding contact to contact list
                            eventosList.add(contact);
                        }
                        Log.d("testttttttt", eventosList.toString());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that `hour` is an Array in `forecastday` and not in `forecast` as you handle it currently.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Perhaps it is, how can I get an fray inside another array? Thanks

Comment: use `porhoraca = eventos.getJSONArray("hour");`

Answer (score -1):

Here is full solution of your problem, you have to just pass response in JsonObject, code is as below

```
       try {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONObject object_location = object.getJSONObject("location");
                JSONObject object_current = object.getJSONObject("current");
                JSONObject object_forecast = object.getJSONObject("forecast");

                String name = object_location.getString("name");
                String region = object_location.getString("region");
                String country = object_location.getString("country");
                String lat = object_location.getString("lat");
                String lon = object_location.getString("lon");
                String tz_id = object_location.getString("tz_id");
                String localtime_epoch = object_location.getString("localtime_epoch");
                String localtime = object_location.getString("localtime");

                String last_updated_epoch = object_current.getString("last_updated_epoch");
                String last_updated = object_current.getString("last_updated");
                String temp_c = object_current.getString("temp_c");
                String temp_f = object_current.getString("temp_f");
                String is_day = object_current.getString("is_day");
                String wind_mph = object_current.getString("wind_mph");
                String wind_kph = object_current.getString("wind_kph");
                String wind_degree = object_current.getString("wind_degree");
                String wind_dir = object_current.getString("wind_dir");
                String pressure_mb = object_current.getString("pressure_mb");
                String pressure_in = object_current.getString("pressure_in");
                String precip_mm = object_current.getString("precip_mm");
                String precip_in = object_current.getString("precip_in");
                String humidity = object_current.getString("humidity");
                String cloud = object_current.getString("cloud");
                String feelslike_c = object_current.getString("feelslike_c");
                String feelslike_f = object_current.getString("feelslike_f");

                JSONObject object_condition = object_current.getJSONObject("condition");

                String text = object_condition.getString("text");
                String icon = object_condition.getString("icon");
                String code = object_condition.getString("code");

                JSONArray array_forecastday = object_forecast.getJSONArray("forecastday");

                for (int i = 0; i < array_forecastday.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject object_fore = array_forecastday.getJSONObject(i);
                    String date = object_fore.getString("date");
                    String date_epoch = object_fore.getString("date_epoch");

                    JSONObject object_day = object_fore.getJSONObject("day");
                    String maxtemp_c = object_day.getString("maxtemp_c");
                    String maxtemp_f = object_day.getString("maxtemp_f");
                    String mintemp_c = object_day.getString("mintemp_c");
                    String mintemp_f = object_day.getString("mintemp_f");
                    String avgtemp_c = object_day.getString("avgtemp_c");
                    String avgtemp_f = object_day.getString("avgtemp_f");
                    String maxwind_mph = object_day.getString("maxwind_mph");
                    String maxwind_kph = object_day.getString("maxwind_kph");
                    String totalprecip_mm = object_day.getString("totalprecip_mm");
                    String totalprecip_in = object_day.getString("totalprecip_in");

                    JSONObject jsonObject_condition = object_day.getJSONObject("condition");
                    String text_cond = jsonObject_condition.getString("text");
                    String icon_cond = jsonObject_condition.getString("icon");
                    String code_cond = jsonObject_condition.getString("code");

                    JSONObject object_astro = object_fore.getJSONObject("astro");
                    String sunrise = object_astro.getString("sunrise");
                    String sunset = object_astro.getString("sunset");
                    String moonrise = object_astro.getString("moonrise");
                    String moonset = object_astro.getString("moonset");


                    JSONArray array_hour = object_fore.getJSONArray("hour");

                    for (int j = 0; j < array_hour.length(); j++) {

                        JSONObject object_hour = array_hour.getJSONObject(j);

                        String  time_epoch = object_hour.getString("time_epoch");
                        String  time = object_hour.getString("time");
                        String  temp_cc = object_hour.getString("temp_c");
                        String  temp_ff = object_hour.getString("temp_f");
                        String  is_day = object_hour.getString("is_day");
                        String  wind_mphh = object_hour.getString("wind_mph");
                        String  wind_kphh = object_hour.getString("wind_kph");
                        String  wind_degreee = object_hour.getString("wind_degree");
                        String  wind_dirr = object_hour.getString("wind_dir");
                        String  pressure_mbb = object_hour.getString("pressure_mb");
                        String  pressure_inn = object_hour.getString("pressure_in");
                        String  precip_mmm = object_hour.getString("precip_mm");
                        String  precip_inn = object_hour.getString("precip_in");
                        String  humidityy = object_hour.getString("humidity");
                        String  cloudd = object_hour.getString("cloud");
                        String  feelslike_cc = object_hour.getString("feelslike_c");
                        String  feelslike_ff = object_hour.getString("feelslike_f");
                        String  windchill_c = object_hour.getString("windchill_c");
                        String  windchill_f = object_hour.getString("windchill_f");
                        String  heatindex_c = object_hour.getString("heatindex_c");
                        String  heatindex_f = object_hour.getString("heatindex_f");
                        String  dewpoint_c = object_hour.getString("dewpoint_c");
                        String  dewpoint_f = object_hour.getString("dewpoint_f");
                        String  will_it_rain = object_hour.getString("will_it_rain");
                        String  will_it_snow = object_hour.getString("will_it_snow");


                        JSONObject jsonObject_hour = object_day.getJSONObject("condition");
                        String text_hour = jsonObject_hour.getString("text");
                        String icon_hour = jsonObject_hour.getString("icon");
                        String code_hour = jsonObject_hour.getString("code");


                    }
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Hope you understand and if facing any problem, let me know, I'll help you.